# Enable hardware acceleration Nvidia Jetsons for image to video encoding

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

I want to encode jpg/png images into h264/h265 mp4 video (h265 is preferred if possible).

I tried using the commands of this question:
[How to create a mp4 video file from PNG images using Gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901428/how-to-create-a-mp4-video-file-from-png-images-using-gstreamer)

I got a mp4 video out with this command:

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -e multifilesrc location="IMG%03d.png" index=1 caps="image/png,framerate=30/1" ! pngdec ! videoconvert ! omxh265enc ! qtmux ! filesink location=image2.mp4
```

or

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -e multifilesrc location="IMG%03d.png" index=1 caps="image/png,framerate=30/1" ! pngdec ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc ! queue ! mp4mux ! filesink location=image3.mp4
```

However according to the docs:

[Accelerated_GStreamer_User_Guide](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/embedded/L4T/r32_Release_v1.0/Docs/Accelerated_GStreamer_User_Guide.pdf)

We can have hardware acceleration with:

```
     H.265 Encode (NVIDIA Accelerated Encode)

gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc ! \
 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, \
format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! nvv4l2h265enc \
bitrate=8000000 ! h265parse ! qtmux ! filesink \
 location=<filename_h265.mp4> -e
```

I changed it a little bit for images as input:

```
 gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="IMG%03d.png" index=1 caps="image/png,framerate=30/1" ! pngdec ! videoconvert ! queue ! nvv4l2h265enc bitrate=8000000 ! h265parse ! qtmux ! filesink  location=output.mp4 -e
```

However I get the error:

```
 WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link queue0 to nvv4l2h264enc0
```

According to the docs in nvv4l2h265enc encoder should be available in GStreamer version 1.0

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA's devtalk forum is the best place for these sorts of questions, but `multifilesrc` probably puts images in normal CPU memory, not in the GPU NvBuffers that the `nvv4l2h265enc` element expects. Furthermore, the encoder only seems to work with NV12-formatted YCbCr data while I think the `multifilesrc` probably outputs in RGB.

The `nvvidconv` element converts  between the "CPU" parts and the "NVIDIA accelerated" parts by moving the data to GPU memory and converting the color space to NV12.

This launch string worked for me:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
multifilesrc location="IMG%03d.png" index=1 caps="image/png,framerate=30/1" ! pngdec \
! nvvidconv \
! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=(string)NV12 \
! queue \
! nvv4l2h265enc bitrate=8000000 \
! h265parse \
! qtmux \
! filesink location=output.mp4 -e
```

The caps string after `nvvidconv` isn't acutally necessary (I also ran successfully without it). `nvv4l2h265enc` also provides caps and `nvvidconv` knows how to change what needs to be changed (color space and memory type). I added it for illustration purposes to let you know what is actually going on.

I hope this helps!